# login error there is an error in logging you into this application please try again later facebook

Tags: ios

My app is Live but Suddenly giving an error in facebook login what to do?
[image]

Comment: But What the solution??

Comment: @VikasRajput there no solution, check thread above, FB team fixed this issue and will deploy it in a few hours

Answer (score 1):

this is facebook sdk error. check below link
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/141267893132714/